# How does this backbone view get it's EL property set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm looking at this Backbone app:

https://github.com/ccoenraets/nodecellar/blob/master/public/js/main.js

and trying to understand how it works. I see that in the main.js file he calls a WineView like this:

```
wineList.fetch({success: function(){
            $("#content").html(new WineListView({model: wineList, page: p}).el);
```

I have a few questions about this:

1) Why call $("#content").... from this point? Isn't one of the points of creating a view object to let that new objects "Render" method handle the HTML injection? In fact his Wine View Object DOES have a render method (here: /public/js/views/winelist.js) so what's this call here good for?

2) Why add the EL property at the end? I thought EL was simply a single tag that the View was "attached" to. If it's just a single tag how does it then generate all the new HTML he's looking for?

3) How does the EL tag even get set in the new view object in th first place? I thought if you didn't explicitly state it then EL defaulted to an empty DIV and I can see nowhere EL defined for this View in his code.

Hope someone can clear this up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does the EL tag even get set here in the first place?

The Backbone code itself creates `el` when you don't specify it.  As you noted, [it defaults to an empty div](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el):

> this.el is created from the view's tagName, className, id and attributes properties, if specified. If not, el is an empty div.

Note that, if the `el` gets created in this way, then it will not be attached to the DOM.  Hence, the code above has to take the `el` property (the view's root tag), and attach it to the DOM under "#content".

> Isn't one of the points of calling creating a view object to let that new objects "Render" method handle the HTML injection

Maybe strictly speaking, but not necessarily.  Backbone.js is agnostic about how you structure applications, and does not impose strict requirements on its models/views.  You'll see lots of different approaches like this in Backbone apps.

Comment: But I thought a call to Jquery's $.html() method was to inject text into the DOM. You seem to be saying that the purpose here is to attach assign the #content tag to the view's EL property. Something seems backwards about that no?

Comment: How does calling Jquery's html() method assign a DOM tag to the View object's EL property?

Comment: @user1813867 no you're right, `.html()` doesn't do anything to the `el` property.  The `el` property refers to the HTML content of the rendered view, right?  So, calling `.html(view.el)` attaches the rendered view to `#content`.

Comment: @user1813867 I see what you're saying, though -- they could have just set `el: "#content"`.  Maybe they want to attach that view to other places, at different points in the app?

Comment: Unless `#content` is going to be used to hold a different view later, then it is easier to let the views create and manage their own `el`s and the overall app can add them to `#content` as needed and remove them when they're no longer needed. Sharing an `el` among views often leads to a mess of manual `delegateEvents`/`undelegateEvents` (which could be hidden inside the standard `view.remove()`) calls and zombies.

Comment: @muistooshort that's a great point, it didn't occur to me.  So if the view owns its own `el`, it also owns the click, etc handlers inside its view; whereas if it had `el: "#content"`, then its handlers would be attached to an element outside its own scope.  This must be why my Backbone app sucked.

Comment: Thank you guys - I think I finally understand. For some reason I had thought the "render" method always wanted to update the DOM. But if it doesn't have a valid DOM object, I didn't realize it still Renders! Then back in the main.js file is where the actual rendered content is injected into the DOM. And according to @mu this is a preferred model. Ah, I feel a little better now.

Comment: My first Backbone app had shared `el`s and attempts at re-using views (didn't know any better) and it end up being a mess of zombies and event chaos. Making each view as self-contained as possible and calling `remove` on old views really simplified things, as did destroying and recreating views instead of trying to re-use them.